# Another \dots or \ldots Problem

Tags: grammar, questionnaire

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Victims!\dots\ Aren't we all?

Victims?\dots\ Aren't we all?

\end{document}
```

That I want

[image]

Like `\dots` or `\ldots`, but not 3 dots only 2 dots.

Comment: @egreg, It has duplicated question. [Solved]

Comment: You can close as duplicate yourself